# Where are arrays stored in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

When we declare an array in C...array is basically a pointer stored with base address of that array..

For ex:

```
int *x=malloc(5);
```

Gives memory for that array 'x' in Heap

Now,my question is that..where does memory will be allocated for this type of array declaration

```
int x1[5];
```

Assume that both 'x' &'x1' are declared in a function.

Where does 'x1' go in memory.
Is it in stack? Or in Heap?

Comment: For `x1` that really depends on where the definition is made. And also note that the C specification doesn't really mention anything about "the stack" or "a stack". That *local* variables *usually* end up on a stack is just an implementation detail.

Comment: Also note that if `x` is defined as a local variable in a function you have *two* allocations: One for the variable `x` itself and one for the memory allocated by the call to `malloc`. And talking about `malloc`, the C specification doesn't really say where or what kind of memory the "heap" is.

Comment: 'When we declare an array in C...array is basically a pointer stored with base address of that array' no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `int x1[5];` doesn't defined in any function, the array x1 is on your program's bss segment , variable x1 is a global array.

If `int x1[5];` defines in any function, the array x1 is on your program's stack during executing this function.

Comment: Is there any way to alloc memory in stack using pointer that is declared in a function??

Comment: please answer to the comment above

Comment: @Nitesh_Adapa Its called "_alloca" or "_malloca"

Answer (score 0):

I believe `int x1[5];` goes on the stack.

Comment: The C standard does not mention a stack. A common way of implementing the behaviors that the C standard requires of objects with automatic storage durations is to use a stack, and so many objects will, if inspected with a debugger or otherwise, be found on a stack. But a C implementation may use other methods. For such a small array, it might keep it entirely in registers.